# Inserir elementos na posição correta em uma lista ordenada

Tags: python, lista, lógica

Gostaria de saber porque esse código não funciona para o exercício abaixo, pois quando se trata dos valores que ficarão intermediários na lista, eles acabam ficando invertidos(o exemplo que eu usava pra testar se iria funcionar era `(15, 5, 6, 7, 8)`).

> Crie um programa onde o usuário possa digitar cinco valores numéricos
>   e cadastre-os em uma lista, já na posição correta de inserção(sem usar
>   o sort()). No final, mostre a lista ordenada na tela.

```
numeros = []
maior = menor = meio = 0
for i in range(0, 5):
    num = int(input("Digite um número: "))
    if i == 0:
        maior = menor = num
        numeros.append(num)
    elif num >= maior:
        maior = num
        numeros.append(num)
    elif num <= menor:
        menor = num
        numeros.insert(0, num)
    elif menor < num < maior:
        if meio == 0:
            meio = num
            numeros.insert(menor < num < maior, num)
        elif meio <= num:
            numeros.insert(meio < num < maior, num)
            meio = num
        elif meio >= num:
            numeros.insert(menor < num < meio, num)
print(numeros)
```

Comment: esse programa está bem confuso - você não precisa dos variáveis "maior" e "menor" - tem que comparar com os números que estão dentro da lista. E mais, alem de nao precisar, você não está pondo valores dentro deles de umjeito que faça sentido - você só preenche "maior" e "menor" dentro das condições do "if"

Comment: Quando você faz ```numeros.insert(menor < num < meio, num)``` o primeiro parâmetro é algo que deveria ser um inteiro que significa aonde vai ser inserido. Você está passando algo que vai ser verdadeiro ou falso (a<b<c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos problemas está em `numeros.insert(menor < num < maior, num)`.

A expressão `menor < num < maior` é uma comparação (verifica se `num` está entre `menor` e `maior`), cujo resultado será um *booleano* (ou seja, `True` ou `False`). Só que um *booleano* em Python, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-boolean-values), em contextos numéricos é interpretado como os valores 1 (`True`) e 0 (`False`). Exemplo:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]

# mudando a posição zero
lista[False] = 10
# mudando a posição 1
lista[True] = 20

print(lista) # [10, 20, 3]
```

Ou seja, em vez do resultado de uma comparação, você deveria passar apenas o valor do índice.

---

Dito isso, você não precisa percorrer toda a lista - e nem fazer um monte de `if`/`elif` - para encontrar a posição correta. Como estamos sempre garantindo que a lista estará ordenada, você pode começar a busca do meio da lista.

Se o número a ser inserido for menor que o elemento do meio, você verifica a primeira metade da lista, se for maior, verifique a segunda metade, e siga fazendo isso até encontrar a posição correta:

```
lista = []
for _ in range(5):
    n = int(input('digite o número: '))
    # se a lista for vazia, insere
    if not lista:
        lista.append(n)
    else:
        # procura a posição
        inicio, fim = 0, len(lista)
        while inicio < fim:
            meio = (inicio + fim) // 2
            if n < lista[meio]:
                fim = meio
            else:
                inicio = meio + 1
        lista.insert(inicio, n)
```

Para verificar se a lista é vazia eu fiz `if not lista`, já que [uma lista vazia é considerada `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth).

Só para ilustrar como funciona o algoritmo (tudo bem que para uma lista pequena como essa, que só vai ter 5 elementos, não faz diferença, mas imagine uma lista de tamanho arbitrário). Supondo que a lista tem 1000 elementos, eu começo a busca pelo elemento 500.

Se o número for maior que o elemento da posição 500, eu verifico a segunda metade (ou seja, agora eu pego o elemento do meio da segunda metade, que está na posição 750). Se o número for menor que o elemento da posição 500, eu verifico a primeira metade (pego o elemento da posição 250 e vejo se o número deve estar antes ou depois dele - e depedendo do caso, pego a posição 125 ou 375, e assim vai).

E continuo fazendo isso, estreitando cada vez mais meu espaço de busca (pois vou pegando o elemento do meio da metade da metade da lista, depois da metade da metade da metade, etc - eu não preciso verificar o restante da lista pois os passos anteriores já me garantiram que o elemento não deve ser inserido lá). Isso só é possível porque eu sempre garanto que a lista está ordenada.

Fazer assim é bem mais eficiente do que percorrer toda a lista (ou fazer uma cadeia complicada de `if`/`elif`). Mesmo que a lista tenha 1 bilhão de elementos, em cerca de 30 passos eu consigo encontrar a posição correta.

---

Na verdade, nem precisaria verificar se a lista está vazia:

```
lista = []
for _ in range(5):
    n = int(input('digite o número: '))
    inicio, fim = 0, len(lista)
    while inicio < fim:
        meio = (inicio + fim) // 2
        if n < lista[meio]:
            fim = meio
        else:
            inicio = meio + 1
    lista.insert(inicio, n)
```

Quando a lista é vazia, tanto `inicio` quanto `fim` terão o valor zero, então não entrará no `while` e o elemento será inserido normalmente na lista.

---

Sei que é um exercício, mas em todo caso, a linguagem já tem isso pronto no [módulo `bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import insort
lista = []
for _ in range(5):
    insort(lista, int(input('digite o número:')))
```

Comment: Eu não sabia que comparação recebia valor de True ou False. Consegui refazer o programa com as dicas e correções, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

esse  programa ficou muito, muito, mais complicado do que era pra ser. Mas muito.não é possível "arruma-lo" - melhor escrever outro.

Dá pra ler o comentário acima como uma 'bronca' - mas não é a ideia - bem-vindo, e obrigado por usar a plataforma. E sim, quando estamos aprendendo, algumas coisas não são claras - e algum conceito que aprendemos as vezes pode parecer um "canivete suiço" que faz tudo.
Então, sem sentimentos ruins - o programa que você fez faz parte de uma etapa do aprendizado - assim como faz "amassar, jogar fora, e começar de novo" - ele ficou confuso - com variáveis que não fazem sentido, não vale mesmo a pena tentar destrinchar e corrigi-lo.  Vamos passar uma regua e pensar sobre o problema:

- a dica é a seguinte: depois de perguntar um número (input), voce tem que percorrer a lista para achar o lugar do próximo número - então você precisa de um "for" dentro do primeiro "for" (pode ser um while, se preferir) - mas tentar adivinhar onde fica o novo número na base do "if...elif" sem percorrer a lista é inviável - e se em vez de cinco elementos,  lista tivesse 300?

A estrutura básica tem que ser:

```
lista = []
for i in range(comprimento_desejado):
    num = int(input("digite o numero: ")
    for posicao, elemento in enumerate(lista):
        # aqui voce poe um unico if e decide
        # se insere o novo número ou não
    # aqui, fora do "for" internom você testa se o número ainda
    # não foi inserido, se não foi, acrescenta-o
    # o final da lista
```

Só isso.
Explico o "enumerate" - ele é uma função especial do Python que pega
cada elemento de uma sequência e devolve a posição (índice) e mais o elemento - 
e aí você pode usar duas varíaveis num `for`  - uma com a posição, outra com o
elemento. Os dois trechos abaixo são equivalentes:

```
for posicao, elemento in enumerate(lista):
    ...
```

e

```
for posicao in range(len(lista)):
    elemento = lista[posicao]
   ...
```

Comment: Por que o negativo? Se eu fosse responder usaria o mesmo código.

Comment: Alguém não deve ter gostado de eu ter dado tanta ênfase no texto ao fato do programa na pergunta estar complicado e confuso. Mas ele está. :-) .

Comment: coloqeui um parágrafo pra dizer que a culpa não é do AP que o programa está "muito, muito complicado'  - mas duvido que quem votou negativo volte aqui pra dizer se esse era o problema.  No mais, negativo faz parte.

Comment: Consegui refazer o programa, obrigado! (inclusive eu entendi o que você quis dizer, não foi meu o negativo, a demora pra responder os comentários foi porque estava quebrando a cabeça no pycharm pra entender)

Comment: Só queria deixar registrado que enfatizar que o código está confuso (ou fazer qualquer outro comentário sobre aspectos técnicos) **não** deveria ser motivo pra downvote (assumindo que foi esse o motivo, claro, infelizmente não dá pra ler a mente de quem votou...)