# Como ordenar uma lista através de um atributo de um objeto?

Tags: python

Eu estou fazendo uma atividade, e queria fazer com que a lista saísse ordenada alfabeticamente a partir do nome do projeto, alguém teria alguma solução ?

```py
class Projeto:

    def __init__(self, nomep, contato):  
        self.nomep = nomep
        self.contato = contato

    def mudar_contato(self, contato_antigo, contato_novo):
        if self.contato == contato_antigo:
            self.contato = contato_novo
            return True 
        else:
            return False  

class Interface:

    projeto = []

    def cadastrar_projeto(self):
        nomep = input('Quais é o nome do projeto?\n')
        contato = input('Quais é a contato desejada?\n')

        self.projeto.append(Projeto(nomep, contato))
        print('Projeto adicionado!')

    def listar_projetos(self):
        for i, projeto in enumerate(self.projeto):
          print(i, projeto.nomep, projeto.contato)

    def mudar_contato(self):
        numero_projeto = input('Qual é o número de listagem do projeto?')
        numero_projeto = int(numero_projeto)

        contato_antigo = input('Qual é o contato atual?\n')
        contato_novo = input('Qual é o contato desejada?\n')
        sucesso = self.projeto[numero_projeto].mudar_contato(contato_antigo, contato_novo)

        if sucesso:
            print('Alteração realizada!')
        else:
            print('Erro ao tentar alterar contato!')
    
    def excluir_projeto(self):
        numero_projeto = input('Qual é o número de listagem do projeto?')
        numero_projeto = int(numero_projeto)
        self.projeto.pop(numero_projeto)

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            cmd = input('\n1 - Listar projeto\n2 - Cadastrar projeto\n3 - Mudar contato\n4 - Excluir Projeto\n')
            if cmd == '1':
                self.listar_projetos()
            elif cmd == '2':
                self.cadastrar_projeto()
            elif cmd == '3':
                self.mudar_contato()
            elif cmd == '4':
                self.excluir_projeto()
            else:
                print('Opção inexistente')
                continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    interface = Interface()
    interface.loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função `sorted` e introduza um valor para o argumento `key`. Esse valor irá explicar para a função `sorted` qual a lógica a ser aplicada na hora de ordenar os elementos.

Uma forma muito utilizada é usar uma função anônima (lambda) para isso. Ex:

```
def listar_projetos(self):
    for i, projeto in enumerate(sorted(self.projeto, key=lambda p: p.nomep.lower())):
      print(i, projeto.nomep, projeto.contato)
```

Da forma como escrevi, a função `sorted` irá ordenar os projetos na lista `self.projeto` olhando apenas para o atributo `nomep` de cada um deles.

Note que usei o método `lower()` para ordenar (assumi que `nomep` é um string). Isso faz com que letras minúsculas ou maiúsculas não tenham efeito no ordenamento.

Edit: um exemplo simples de método para deletar um projeto da lista (conforme discussão nos comentários).

```
def excluir_projeto_por_nome(self, nome):
    projetos_para_remover = []
    for projeto in self.projeto:
        if projeto.nomep == nome:
            projetos_para_remover.append(projeto)
    self.projeto = [p for p in self.projeto if p not in projetos_para_remover]
```

Comment: De fato funcionou, porém a função de excluir pelo index está utilizando o valor inicial, antes da ordenação, teria algum jeito de atualizar os valores do index de acordo com a ordenação, ou alguma outra sugestão ?

Comment: Sugiro uma das duas abordagens: manter o número do projeto como um atributo do projeto em si, tornando-se independente de sua posição na lista (ex: adicione o atributo `self.nump` ao `__init__` da classe `Projeto`), ou manter a lista `projeto` de sua classe `Interface` sempre ordenada - isto é, no método `cadastrar_projeto`, ao invés de usar o método `append` da lista, descubra em que posição da lista o projeto deve ser inserido para mantê-la ordenada e use o método `insert` de listas.

Comment: Como eu faço para que o insert descubra em que posição ele precisa ser inserido pra mantê-la ordenada ?

Comment: Isso já um problema inteiramente diferente, dê uma olhada em outras perguntas como https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446761/inserir-elementos-na-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-correta-em-uma-lista-ordenada por exemplo.

Comment: Tem alguma maneira mais simples em que eu apenas digite o nome e ele selecione o mesmo e delete ?

Comment: Você pode criar um método `excluir_projeto_por_nome` para isso - dado um nome como argumento, o método itera sobre a lista de projetos, encontra o(s) projeto(s) cujo nome é igual ao nome dado como argumento, e por fim os remove da lista.

Comment: Poderia exemplificar ? Não sou da área de computação, porém meu curso exige essa matéria e tô tendo muita dificuldade.

Comment: Editei minha resposta para incluir um exemplo de como fazer isso, espero que esteja claro.

Comment: Ele me retornou esse erro lá no loop:
TypeError: excluir_projeto_por_nome() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nome'

Comment: Você passou o nome de projeto para excluir? Ex: `self.excluir_projeto(nome='meuprojeto01')`.

Comment: É que é necessário um input para que ele leia o nome do projeto a ser excluído. No caso, eu teria que colocar um nome = input("") no método ?

Comment: Pode ser, nesse caso você precisaria remover o argumento `nome` da definição do método: `def excluir_projeto_por_nome(self):`. Ou então colocar o input dentro do seu método `loop`. Fica a seu critério.

Comment: E no caso do mudar contato, já que o índice não é mais necessário, tem alguma ideia de como ficaria ?